# Finding a loopless path passing through a series of nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given a directed graph, which has n points, there are k "must pass" points, where k < n-2.

How do I find a path from a start node to an end node that passes through all the "must pass" points without revisiting any nodes? Maybe this is a NP-complete problem... seems like TSP is very similar to this problem.

Comment: I think you should consider it as a finding the loop less path  problem.And the constrain is there are K must pass points (k < n - 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is indeed NP-hard. To see this, you can reduce the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) to this one by starting with the original graph, adding in two new nodes not connected to anything, then asking for a path that passes through every node in the graph except for those two new ones.

You may be able to use some techniques designed for finding long paths in graphs, like [color coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color-coding) or dynamic programming techniques, to avoid a brute-force search, but given the nature of this problem I doubt you'll be able to do much better than brute-force.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I'm trying to describe it properly, as I'm not a native English speaker.